# Understanding getOrElse usage and dotless function composition

Tags: scala

I have following codes:

```
sealed trait Option[+A] {

  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
    case None => None
    case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
  }

  def getOrElse[B>:A](default: => B): B = this match {
    case None => default
    case Some(a) => a
  }

  def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] =
    map(f) getOrElse None
}
case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

The body of the `flatMap` function, how does it works? It is not a function composition. What kind of function call it is?

How to use `getOrElse` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map(f) getOrElse None` is equivalent to the expression `map(f).getOrElse(None)` which simply call the `map()` function with the input `f` and then call the `getOrElse` on the result, which returns the value x for `Some(x)` or `None` in case map returns with `None`.

`Some(5).getOrElse(0)` will return 5
`None.getOrElse(0)` will return 0

Comment: Do `map(f)` return the object Option, that because I can do method chaining?

Comment: Yes, getOrElse is defined on the Option.